# NSolve and FindRoot failing to evaluate

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

So I am integrating a `Piecewise` function and then using `NSolve` to find out where the limits of integration lie to satisfy an equation.

```
NSolve[Pi == Integrate[Piecewise[{{(2 Sin[x1])/Sin[θ], x1 < θ < -Pi - x1}}, 1.999], {θ, -5 Pi/6, -Pi/6}], x1, Reals]
```

This code works perfectly fine, returning the desired result $x_1 \sim -2.49$.

However, when the limits of the integration are slightly more complicated, as in this example:

```
 NSolve[4.36282952905673` == Integrate[
Piecewise[{{1.999, -255 Pi/256 < θ < x1}, {(2 Sin[x1])/
  Sin[θ], 
  x1 < θ < - π + ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {1.001, - π + 
    ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {(
  2 Sin[x1])/Sin[θ], 
  ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < -Pi - x1}, {1.999, -Pi - 
    x1 < θ < -(Pi/256)}}, 
1.999], {θ, -255 Pi/256, -Pi/256}], x1, Reals]
```

`NSolve` runs forever. I have also tried using `FindRoot` with a sensible guess of $x_1 = -2.71$, which again fails to complete running:

```
FindRoot[4.36282952905673` == 
 Integrate[
Piecewise[{{1.999, -255 Pi/256 < θ < x1}, {(2 Sin[x1])/
  Sin[θ], 
  x1 < θ < - π - ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {1.001, - π - 
    ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {(
  2 Sin[x1])/Sin[θ], 
  ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < -Pi - x1}, {1.999, -Pi - 
    x1 < θ < -(Pi/256)}}, 
1.999], {θ, -255 Pi/256, -Pi/256}], {x1, -2.71}]
```

I am motivated that the root $x_1$ is close to $-2.71$ as the following:

```
 ReleaseHold[
Hold[Integrate[
Piecewise[{{1.999, -255 Pi/256 < θ < x1}, {(2 Sin[x1])/
   Sin[θ], 
   x1 < θ < - π - ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {1.001, - π -
      ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {(
   2 Sin[x1])/Sin[θ], 
   ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < -Pi - x1}, {1.999, -Pi - 
     x1 < θ < -(Pi/256)}}, 
 1.999], {θ, -255 Pi/256, -Pi/256}]] /. x1 -> -2.71]
```

Gives the integral as 4.34719, very close to the desired `4.36282952905673`.

Any pointers on why my `NSolve` or `FindRoot` code is not working? Could it be something to do with `Hold`? I had to `Hold` the `Integrate` to get `ReplaceAll` to work.

**Edit**

I have found a solution that works, though it does require me to have a fairly good guess of where the root is via trial and error with the integral block as posted above.

```
g[x1_?NumericQ] := 
Integrate[
  Piecewise[{{1.999, -255 Pi/256 < θ < x1}, {(2 Sin[x1])/
  Sin[θ], 
 x1 < θ < -π - ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {1.001, -π - 
   ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < 
  ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]]}, {(2 Sin[x1])/Sin[θ], 
 ArcSin[2 Sin[x1]] < θ < -Pi - x1}, {1.999, -Pi - 
   x1 < θ < -(Pi/256)}}, 1.999], {θ, -255 Pi/256, -Pi/256}]

FindRoot[4.36282952905673` == g[x1], {x1, -2.8, -2.69}, Method -> "Secant"]
```

This gives $x_1 = -2.70523$ as required.

Comment: Since you are using `g` only with numerical values, I'd suggest that you use `NIntegrate` rather than `Integrate` for the numerical integration. Apart from that, you might want to move your solution to a self-answer, rather than adding it to your question.